# iOS stream device camera video feed to local html page in wkwebview

Tags: html, ios, streaming, wkwebview, hybrid

I want to capture the video using device camera using native code and stream it to local html page in webview.

There is no information on how to stream to a local html page which is loaded in the WKWebView

AFAIK I couldn't find any way to achieve this and it seems impossible to achieve ?

Thanks !